# Use Active Directory on a host computer and not only on the server?

Tags: active-directory

I want to have Active directory on my own PC and not only remotely 
connect to the server every time I want to change something in the Active Directory. How can I achieve that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't. But you can install a windows server in a VM, so it would work. https://superuser.com is a very nice site for similar power user things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Remote Server Administration Tools (RSAT) to bring the management tools on your computer.

You can download RSAT for Windows 10 here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

Comment: Thank you so much! I have no idea why people downvote my question.. do u?

Comment: I think it's because you said "I want to have Active directory on my own PC" 
Which could be interpreted as "I want to have active directory *running* on my PC" (hosting the directory database etc...) but in fact, you just want to have the management tools on your computer.